# Books about Monte Carlo Simulation on derivatives with Python

Tags: monte-carlo, derivatives, python, simulations, books

I am looking for a good reference for Monte Carlo simulation applied to derivatives with Python. Most books I found until now deal with C++... I have found "Derivatives Analytics with Python" by Yves Hilpisch, has anyone already read it or has a good reference to suggest?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe there's not any books on it because Python is not really recommended for Monte Carlo? MC is time consuming and Python is slow

Answer (score 2):

I really liked another book from Yves Hilpisch

Python for Finance by Yves Hilpisch

There are several chapters where he goes through the development of a pricing library.

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032441.do